# PHPMailer 6.9 - NOT sending email with CRONJOB

Tags: php, email, cron, phpmailer

When I load the script in the **browser**, it works just fine,
but when I use a **cronjob** to run the script, **It is not working**.
I would like the script to run both in browser and when called by a cron job.

Here is the **script.php**

```
    require_once 'init.php'; 
   
    $msg_id     = "custom_id" . time();
    $mb_html    = 'html body';
    $mb_text    = 'text body';

    $send = new Email();
    $success_mail_sent = $send->sendEmailWithPHPMailer(
            false,                      //$smtp true / false
            5,                          //$priority, 1/3/5
            $msg_id,                    //$msg_id,
            $configs['my_email'],       // $to_email,
            ucfirst(DOMAIN_NAME),       //$to_name,
            null,                       // $add_cc_email (null if we want without CC)
            null,                       // $subject_emoji, null / emoji
            'test',                     // $subject_text,
            $mb_html,
            $mb_text,
            false,                      // $getAcopy to my other mail
            'kkk'                       // script origin
            );
    if ($success_mail_sent == null) { // sending failed
        // do error handling stuff
    } else { // sending succeeded
       // do mail sent stuff
    }
    echo $success_mail_sent;
```

The **Email.php** class that is called in the script.php looks like this:

```
    <?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;



    class Email {

        public static function sendEmailWithPHPMailer(
                $smtp,
                $priority,
                $msg_id,
                $to_email,
                $to_name,
                $add_cc_email=null,
                $subject_emoji,
                $subject_text,
                $mail_body_html,
                $mail_body_text,
                $getAcopy,
                $origine=null) {





    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/site_settings.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    if($smtp == true){
        $mail->isSMTP();                                                                                    
        $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';                                            
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'username@domain.com';                                    
        $mail->Password = 'password';                                       
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                              
        $mail->Port = 587; 
        $mail->ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    }

                    
    $mail->Priority = $priority;
    $mail->setFrom($configs['my_email'], ucfirst(DOMAIN_NAME));   
    $mail->Sender=$configs['my_email'];                           
    $mail->addAddress($to_email, $to_name);                   
    
    if($getAcopy == true){
        $mail->addBCC($configs['my_other_email'], ucfirst(DOMAIN_NAME));   
    }
    if($add_cc_email !== null){
        $mail->addCC($add_cc_email);        // For CC
    }

    $mail->addReplyTo($configs['my_email'], ucfirst(DOMAIN_NAME));
    $mail->BouncedTo = $configs['my_email'];                        
    $mail->MessageID = $msg_id;                                             
    $mail->Date = date('r', time());
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                                   
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                                    
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->Subject = $subject_emoji.$subject_text;
    $mail->Body  = $mail_body_html;
    $mail->AltBody = $mail_body_text;

    if(!$mail->send()) { 
        // echo 'Message could not be sent. ';
        // echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $success_mail_sent = null;

    } else { 
        // echo 'Message has been sent<br>
        // MessageID: '. $msg_id;

        $success_mail_sent = $mail->getLastMessageID();

    }
    unset($mail);

    return ($success_mail_sent);


    }

  }
```

also, the **init.php** file that I call at the beginning of the script.php looks like this:

```
     <?php // initialization file that we include in each page
     session_start();
     spl_autoload_register(function($class){
         $class = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class); 
         $phpMailerClassesArray = array('DSNConfigurator', 'Exception', 'OAuth.php', 'OAuthTokenProvider', 'PHPMailer', 'POP3', 'SMTP');
         if(in_array($class, $phpMailerClassesArray)){
                 require_once 'classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/' .$class. '.php';
          } else {
                 require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
          }


    });
```

NOTE: There are 2 folders where I have classes: classes/ (for all classes) and classes/PHMailer/PHMailer/ (just for the php mailer classes)
**What am I doing wrong? how can I solve this? Thanks!**

Comment: You don't say exactly how it's failing, but It's likely to be a permissions problem. If the user the cron job is running as does not have permission to access the scripts, it won't be able to run.

Comment: it has the permission, because if in the same script i put a code to create a .txt file and write something in it, it works in cronjob... the problem arises when I call the new Mail(); I dont get any errors, but it is just not working..

Comment: it simply does not work, no php errors, no output...

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work). Do some [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/). We can't magically guess what is happening to your script without any meaningful information, sorry. It's possible https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting is also going to be useful

Comment: Oh and make sure [PHP error logging is enabled](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#tldr), in case any exceptions from the cron script can be logged

Comment: it does not work, it means that when the script.php is run by the conjob, Ib this case i dont get error from PhPmailer, because it does not send email. it is possible that it does not instatiate the new Email() class. also phperror.txt does not update when script is run by the cronjob... but when i run the script in the browser it logs the php errors.

Comment: remember PHP in cron will run as command-line PHP, which has different config than the web settings, so make sure error logging is configured in that php.ini file as well. `it is possible that it does not instatiate the new Email() class`...perhaps. Or 100 other things could be wrong. There's no point in guessing or speculating though - if you're unsure what the code is doing then add some of your own logging to it as well so you can see exactly where it does and doesn't go.

Comment: looking forward to other opinions

Comment: Why, what don't you agree with from my remarks? We can't run your code and don't have access to your environment. So without any debugging information, you're simply asking people to guess. That isn't a  productive use of anyone's time - not least yours -, and isn't something that we tend to do at Stackoverflow. We expect people to present a concrete problem based on concrete information about what's happening to the code when you run it.

Comment: e.g. You said `it is possible that it does not instatiate the new Email() class`...ok, well if that's your theory you should go and investigate it by debugging your code thoroughly. Then come back with the results, so we know for sure, and can rule it in or out of the problem. Since the code works in the web environment, then clearly the code itself is not going to reveal the issue on its own...something is different in the environment which is preventing the email from being sent. Only debugging it and ensuring errors are being properly logged will enable you to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: your debugging advice helped and inspired me, thanks! After some minute debugging I have come to the conclusion that the path to the site_settings.php was wrong. I corrected it, and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

After some minute debugging, I have come to the conclusion that the path to the site_settings.php was wrong:

```
  require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/site_settings.php';
```

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was null... and the string that remained was: require '/path/to/site_settings.php'.
The path shouldn't have started with "/".
So by not loading the site_settings.php it was unable to provide sender email and sender name, along with other variables that were required in the PHPMailer class. So it was not sending mail.

I corrected it, and now it works like a charm.

In this case, in the Email.php class was corrected.
Thank everyone for the help and inspiration! Specially ADyson, cheers brother!